# JavaScript Canvas object

Tags: javascript, canvas

I want to create a canvas object in memory, and not require a HTML `<canvas>` tag. Is this possible?

With this code:

```
var canvas = new Canvas();
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
```

I get this error message: `Uncaught ReferenceError: Canvas is not defined`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be able to create the element with JavaScript:

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`document.createElement("canvas")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createElement) instead. There is no `Canvas` constructor for [canvases](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLCanvasElement), as you know it from `Image` for images or `Option` for options - those are the sole exceptions.